# Proving that a set of connectives { # , T } is functionally complete / adequate

Tags: logic

I am a little bit stuck trying to prove if a set of logical connectives {#, T} is functionally complete. For the ternary connective # we have;

#(a,b,c) = T if there are 2 T's,

#(a,b,c) = F otherwise.

We also have T being the connective 'veritum', where every valuation sends it to true.

Now I have proved completeness or incompleteness of sets including ternary connectives before, but this is one case where I cannot see a way to begin. I think it may be the inclusion of the nullary connective that is throwing me off. Any help would be very much appreciated on this!

Comment: One thing you can try, if you can't think of anything else, is to start writing down simple formulas of $\#$  and $T$, calculate their truth tables, and see if you get anything you recognize.  Even if you don't , getting familiar with the two new operations can't hurt.

Comment: I would first try looking only at triples $(a,a,a)$ where $a=T$ or $a=F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to show completeness:

We know that $\{ \neg, \land \}$ is a complete set, so let's see if we can capture both $\neg$ and $\land$ with the $\#$ and $\top$

Well:

$\#(a,\top,\top)$ has already two $T$'s, so would be $T$ if $a$ is F, and $F$ if $a$ is $T$. So, this captures the $\neg$, i.e. $$\neg a = \#(a,\top,\top)$$

How about $\land$?  OK, let's try ... what does $\#(a,b,c)$ do? We want it to be true iff $A$ and $b$ are both T ... so we want $c$ to always be $F$.  OK, so we want that $c$ is the opposite of $\top$, i.e. $c$ should be the negation of $\top$. OK, we just saw how to do negation, so make $c=\#(\top,\top,\top)$.  And so that gives us that: $$a \land b = \#(a,b,\#(\top,\top,\top))$$

Comment: Thank you! I was completely looking over the fact that ⊤ could just be substituted in for a,b,c. Rookie mistake! 
Out of curiosity, how would you go about proving that # itself is incomplete? I would normally look for a counter-example, but here I'm not too sure how to prove it.

Comment: @J.Clarke You're welcome! :) To show that $\#$ by itself is incomplete, note that it is incapable to capture any function $f$ for which $f(F,F,F)=T$

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:** It's enough to express negation and conjunction. 
We have $\#(\top, \top, x) =\lnot x$, in particular, $\bot=\#(\top, \top, \top)$.

> Try $\#(\bot, x, y)$.